# NHibernate Criteria Query - Detached query and subquery: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: nhibernate

I'm learning NHibernate Criteria Queries and I have an issue hope you guys can help me.

I have this model:

```cs
public class Cat
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual char Sex { get; set; }
    public virtual float Weight { get; set; }
    public virtual CatStore? CatStore { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Version { get; set; }
}
```

Then I run this query but it causes an exception at line `var cats...`:

```cs
var avgWeight = DetachedCriteria
    .For<Cat>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Avg("Weight"));
using var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();
var cats = session
    .CreateCriteria<Cat>()
    .Add(Subqueries.Gt("Weight", avgWeight))
    .List();
```

Exception:

```
  Message: 
    NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException : could not execute query
    [ SELECT this_.CatId as catid1_3_0_, this_.Version as version2_3_0_, this_.Name as name3_3_0_, this_.Sex as sex4_3_0_, this_.Weight as weight5_3_0_, this_.CatStoreId as catstoreid6_3_0_ FROM Cat this_ WHERE ? > (SELECT avg(cast(this_0_.Weight as FLOAT(53))) as y0_ FROM Cat this_0_) ]
      Name:cp0 - Value:Weight
    [SQL: SELECT this_.CatId as catid1_3_0_, this_.Version as version2_3_0_, this_.Name as name3_3_0_, this_.Sex as sex4_3_0_, this_.Weight as weight5_3_0_, this_.CatStoreId as catstoreid6_3_0_ FROM Cat this_ WHERE ? > (SELECT avg(cast(this_0_.Weight as FLOAT(53))) as y0_ FROM Cat this_0_)]
      ----> System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
  Stack Trace: 
    Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder)
    CriteriaLoaderExtensions.LoadAllToList[T](IList`1 loaders, ISessionImplementor session)
    SessionImpl.List[T](CriteriaImpl criteria)
    CriteriaImpl.List[T]()
    CriteriaImpl.List()
    CatStoreTests.DetachQueryAsSubqueryTest() line 284
    --FormatException
    Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
    IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
    Convert.ToDouble(Object value)
    DoubleType.Set(DbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
    NullableType.NullSafeSet(DbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, ISessionImplementor session)
    CriteriaNamedParameterSpecification.Bind(DbCommand command, IList`1 multiSqlQueryParametersList, Int32 singleSqlParametersOffset, IList`1 sqlQueryParametersList, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
    CriteriaNamedParameterSpecification.Bind(DbCommand command, IList`1 sqlQueryParametersList, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISessionImplementor session)
    SqlCommandImpl.Bind(DbCommand command, ISessionImplementor session)
    Loader.PrepareQueryCommand(QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean scroll, ISessionImplementor session)
    Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder)
    Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder)
    Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IResultTransformer forcedResultTransformer, QueryCacheResultBuilder queryCacheResultBuilder)
```

I copy the generated query in the exception, replace ***?*** with ***Weight*** and it can be executed success against database.

Could you guys please tell me what I was wrong here?

Comment: You need to provide full exception stack trace

Comment: hi @RomanArtiukhin, i've just added the exception stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subqueries.Gt` is used for comparing subquery results with parameter value like `Subqueries.Gt(11.5, avgSubquery)`. Exception is thrown on attempt to convert `Weight` string to double parameter value.

You need to use `Subqueries.PropertyGt` instead:

```
.Add(Subqueries.PropertyGt("Weight", avgWeight))
```

Comment: You're right! I've just tried and it's exactly as I expected. The `Subqueries.Gt()` I used is from the NHibernate documentation (https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries), it's a mistake from them. Anyway thank you!